# Solution File in VS 2008

Tags: c#, visual-studio, projects-and-solutions

I have referenced a config file that is located in a solution folder. I then reference that file in my projects.  How do I get that config file into the bin directory when I publish the project?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Select the file and then Properties->Copy to Output Directory->Copy Always